# ExtJs Gridpanel Json store update

Tags: json, extjs

How to update one row in Json store .

I am adding record for json store and how to update that particular record.

Comment: How do you add that record and why does the store not load automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using ExtJs 3.3.1 you can do the following:

```
var record = jsonStore.getAt(1);
```

The record variable will then be of type Ext.data.Record. I am using jsonStore.getAt() as an example here but I would recommend you use jsonStore.getById()

Assuming that your records have fields named 'FirstName' and 'LastName' you can then update the values of that specific 
record by executing the following:

```
record.set('FirstName', 'John');
record.set('LastName', 'Smith');
record.commit();
```

I highly recommend you have a look at the ExtJs documentation as there are some really good example in there :) good luck